# Alternative to TzScan API

Tags: tzscan, api

Because TzScan will shut down soon and I need an alternative API to help me to calculate delegators rewards. I reviewed Tezos.id API and I can't find the necessary functionality to help me with that. I am  using TzScan API function: 
/v3/rewards_split/{account_hash} to get all necessary information. Do you know any other Tezos APIs to help me to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will help you find what you're looking for. https://tzstats.com/docs/api/index.html#introduction. I've searched this resource and found numerous endpoints related to delegates, rewards, account hashes, delegation, etc.

EDIT: Yesterday, they've also announced plans to go open-source. https://tzstats.com/blog/next-gen-blockchain-indexing-for-tezos/.

2nd EDIT: Baking Bad announced they are developing an API called TZKT, a lightweight, baking focused, account explorer: https://tzkt.io/.

3rd EDIT: Removed (Thanks)

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful.

Comment: Baking Bad also temporarily provides a subset of the TzScan endpoints until they are going live with their account explorer. You can find these endpoints here: https://mystique.tzkt.io

Comment: Concerning the 3rd edit, these endpoints won't be of any help, as they are providing data from Dune, not from Tezos. I suggest to remove this edit.